# SVG image within an absolutely positioned div is different on Firefox than Chrome

Tags: html, css, text, flexbox, graphical-logo

I have the following web page:

http://designsystem.foamfactory.io/current/components/preview/main.html

It's basically a set of text, along with a couple of SVG images. In order to get the effect that I want (the hex bolts should be overlaid in a specific position on the text), I use absolute positioning within a relatively positioned container.

The actual HTML code and CSS are fairly simple, and outlined in this codepen:

https://codepen.io/jwir3/pen/ZEzRKyz

The associated HTML is:

```
<div class="lockup">
        <img class="lockup-logo logo-medium" src="http://designsystem.foamfactory.io/current/dist/assets/logos/Logo.svg" />
        <div class="textmark textmark-medium">
            <div id="hex-bolt-f-top">
                <img src="http://designsystem.foamfactory.io/current/dist/assets/misc/Hex%20Bolt.svg" />
            </div>
            <div id="hex-bolt-f-bottom">
                <img src="http://designsystem.foamfactory.io/current/dist/assets/misc/Hex%20Bolt.svg" />
            </div>
            <div id="hex-bolt-y-middle">
                <img src="http://designsystem.foamfactory.io/current/dist/assets/misc/Hex%20Bolt.svg" />
            </div>
            <div id="hex-bolt-y-bottom">
                <img src="http://designsystem.foamfactory.io/current/dist/assets/misc/Hex%20Bolt.svg" />
            </div>
            <div class="textmark-text">Foamfactor<span class="last-letter">y</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="empty"></div>
    </div>
```

and CSS:

```
    .lockup {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }


  .lockup .empty {
    -ms-flex-positive: 4;
    flex-grow: 4;
  }


  .lockup-logo {
    display: inline;
  }


  .textmark {
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 0px;
    flex: 1 1 0;
    margin-left: .2em;
  }


  .textmark .textmark-text {
    display: block;
    color: black !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Staatliches";
    line-height: 1.0;
    letter-spacing: -.04em;
  }


  .textmark.textmark-large {
    font-size: 200pt;
  }


  .textmark.textmark-large .textmark-text::first-letter,

  .textmark.textmark-large .textmark-text .last-letter {
    font-size: 300pt;
  }


  .textmark.textmark-large .textmark-text .last-letter {
    margin-left: -.04em;
  }


  .textmark.textmark-medium {
    font-size: 80pt;
  }


  .textmark.textmark-medium .textmark-text::first-letter,

  .textmark.textmark-medium .textmark-text .last-letter {
    font-size: 120pt;
  }


  .textmark.textmark-medium .textmark-text .last-letter {
    margin-left: -.04em;
  }


  .textmark.textmark-small {
    font-size: 40pt;
  }


  .textmark.textmark-small .textmark-text::first-letter,

  .textmark.textmark-small .textmark-text .last-letter {
    font-size: 60pt;
  }


  .textmark.textmark-small .textmark-text .last-letter {
    margin-left: -.04em;
  }


  .textmark.textmark-tiny {
    font-size: 24pt;
  }


  .textmark.textmark-tiny .textmark-text::first-letter,

  .textmark.textmark-tiny .textmark-text .last-letter {
    font-size: 36pt;
  }


  .textmark.textmark-tiny .textmark-text .last-letter {
    margin-left: -.04em;
  }


  .textmark #hex-bolt-f-top img,

  .textmark #hex-bolt-f-bottom img,

  .textmark #hex-bolt-y-bottom img,

  .textmark #hex-bolt-y-middle img {
    width: .08em;
  }


  .textmark #hex-bolt-f-top {
    position: absolute;
    top: -.6em;
    left: .1em;
  }


  .textmark #hex-bolt-f-bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: .1em;
    left: .1em;
  }


  .textmark #hex-bolt-y-bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: .1em;
    right: .2282em;
  }


  .textmark #hex-bolt-y-middle {
    position: absolute;
    top: -.1em;
    right: .2282em;
  }
```

In Chrome, this always looks how I would expect. In Firefox (I'm using Nightly, but I have tried it on the latest release as well), however, the hex bolts on the far right of the div (the "Y") are too far to the right. Even stranger, most of the time it looks fine in Firefox, too, but when I inspect it using dev tools, it changes the width of the box or something, and it gets screwed up until I shift-refresh (a simple refresh won't fix the issue).

I'm fairly certain that the problem lies with the fact that the outermost div for this entire text/logo combination is a flexible box. The reason I have it that way is to center it on the page. Perhaps there is another way to achieve the results I want without this?

More to the point, I'm unclear on why the behavior is different between the two browsers. Have I hit on an area where the specification isn't well defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this solves the issue but you need to correct the first letter

```
.textmark .textmark-text {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to center it with this:

```
.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

That way you only have something like:

```
<body class="frontmatter index">
   <div class="centered">
      <div>
         <div class="lockup">
            <img class="lockup-logo logo-medium" src="../../dist/assets/logos/Logo.svg">
            <div class="textmark textmark-medium">
                <div id="hex-bolt-f-top">
                    <img src="../../dist/assets/misc/Hex Bolt.svg">
                </div>
                <div id="hex-bolt-f-bottom">
                    <img src="../../dist/assets/misc/Hex Bolt.svg">
                </div>
                <div id="hex-bolt-y-middle">
                    <img src="../../dist/assets/misc/Hex Bolt.svg">
                </div>
                <div id="hex-bolt-y-bottom">
                    <img src="../../dist/assets/misc/Hex Bolt.svg">
                </div>
                <div class="textmark-text">Foamfactor<span class="last-letter">y</span></div>
                </div>
                <div class="empty"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h2>An elegant brewery management system for a more civilized age</h2>
     </div>

....

</body>
```

Flexbox might be a little overkill for this in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this didn't actually work for me. I tried a number of different variations on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need check this website:
https://validator.w3.org

and scan your website there that web will tell you where to fix your web struct as I check there is many attribute and tag are missing from your web. you may think this is not the problem that cause your website struct error. So please go to that website and fix what is the error left in your web structure.